# Domain of the definition of a composite function

Tags: functions, education

If $$f(x)= \sqrt{3|x|-x-2} \\ g(x)=\sin(x),$$ then the domain of definition of $(f\circ g)(x)$ is ...?

How do you calculate the domain of a composite function like this?

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you find a single value of x for which the composite function is undefined?

Comment: Hint: Begin by computing the domain and image of each function separately.  For example, $g(x)$ is defined everywhere and its output is between $-1$ and $1$.  Next, what values for $x$ are allowed in $f$?  (what must you know about the value under the square root?)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Observe that $f$ is defined, as a real valued function, if and only if 
\begin{align*}
&&3|x|-x-2&\ge 0\\
\iff && 3|x|&\ge x+2\\
\iff & &9x^2\ge x^2+4x+4 \quad&\text{or}\quad x+2\le 0\\
\iff&&2x^2-x-1\ge0\quad&\text{or}\quad x\le -2\\
\iff&&x\le-\frac{1}{2} \qquad\text{or}\qquad x\ge1\quad&\text{or}\quad x\le -2\\
\iff&&x&\in\big(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2}\big]\cup[1,\infty)
\end{align*}
Now, look for the values of $x$ such that $$\sin x \in\big(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2}\big]\cup[1,\infty)$$